# Change button colors

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, button, colors

I want to change button colors when the user click on it.

The main plan is: every month 10th one worker's button go to red and if the worker done his job then click on the button and it going to be green.

I have no idea what to do.

I already have this code. I just created a window and add a button to it:

```
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddButton(hWnd);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}

void AddButton(HWND hWnd)
{
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Change colors", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        350, 200,
        100, 100,
        hWnd,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL);
}
```

So I tried WM_LBUTTONDOWN. I think this is something when the user click on the button the program will do something. I put in the `switch(msg) case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:`.

But no idea what's next.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: WM_LBUTTONDOWN is not the correct way to detect click on a button (and remember, you can press it with the keyboard as well). Catching the button press is unrelated to the color question, you should figure out how to catch the press event first...

Comment: Take the [tour] and read [ask]. If you're not a developer, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple demo to show how to detect click on a button, and change the color of button when you click on it.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' \
    name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
    processorArchitecture='*' \
    publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
static BOOL flag = false;
ATOM RegisterWndClass(HINSTANCE hInst);

BOOL CreateMainWnd(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow);

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

HINSTANCE hInst;

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hInstPrev, LPWSTR lpszCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex = { 0 };
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES | ICC_USEREX_CLASSES | ICC_BAR_CLASSES |
        ICC_COOL_CLASSES | ICC_TAB_CLASSES | ICC_WIN95_CLASSES |
        ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS | ICC_PAGESCROLLER_CLASS;

    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    MSG msg;

    hInst = hInstance;

    if (!RegisterWndClass(hInstance))
        return NULL;

    if (!CreateMainWnd(hInstance, nCmdShow))
        return NULL;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
};

ATOM RegisterWndClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{

    WNDCLASS wndClass = { 0 };
    wndClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE);
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = L"MainClass";
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;

    return RegisterClass(&wndClass);
}

BOOL CreateMainWnd(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"MainClass", L"Buttons sample",
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - 115,
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - 50,
        230, 100, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
        return FALSE;

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // Owner draw button

        CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON |
            BS_OWNERDRAW, 10, 10, 60, 30, hWnd,
            (HMENU)10001, hInst, NULL);

        // Custom draw button

        CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 80,
            10, 60, 30, hWnd, (HMENU)10002, hInst, NULL);

        // Bitmap button

        HWND hBitmapButton = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE
            | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_BITMAP,
            150, 10, 60, 30, hWnd,
            (HMENU)10003, hInst, NULL);

        HDC hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

        HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

        hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, 55, 25);

        SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

        SetDCBrushColor(hMemDC, RGB(0, 0, 255));

        RECT r = { 0 };
        r.left = 0;
        r.right = 55;
        r.top = 0;
        r.bottom = 25;

        FillRect(hMemDC, &r, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

        DeleteDC(hMemDC);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);

        SendMessage(hBitmapButton, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP,
            (LPARAM)hBitmap);

        return 0;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case 10001:
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Owner draw button clicked", L"Message", NULL);
            return 0;
        case 10002:
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Custom draw button clicked", L"Message", NULL);
            return 0;
        case 10003:
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Bitmap button clicked", L"Message", NULL);
            return 0;
        }
        break;

        // Owner draw button

    case WM_DRAWITEM:
        if (wParam == 10001)
        {
            if (flag == false)
            {
                LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

                SetDCBrushColor(lpDIS->hDC, RGB(255, 0, 0));

                SelectObject(lpDIS->hDC, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

                RoundRect(lpDIS->hDC, lpDIS->rcItem.left, lpDIS->rcItem.top,
                    lpDIS->rcItem.right, lpDIS->rcItem.bottom, 5, 5);
            }
            else 
            {
                LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

                SetDCBrushColor(lpDIS->hDC, RGB(0, 255, 0));

                SelectObject(lpDIS->hDC, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

                RoundRect(lpDIS->hDC, lpDIS->rcItem.left, lpDIS->rcItem.top,
                    lpDIS->rcItem.right, lpDIS->rcItem.bottom, 5, 5);
            }
            flag = !flag;
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;

        // Custom draw button

    case WM_NOTIFY:
        switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
        {
        case NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
            if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->idFrom == 10002)
            {
                LPNMCUSTOMDRAW lpnmCD = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;

                switch (lpnmCD->dwDrawStage)
                {
                case CDDS_PREPAINT:

                    SetDCBrushColor(lpnmCD->hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
                    SetDCPenColor(lpnmCD->hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
                    SelectObject(lpnmCD->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
                    SelectObject(lpnmCD->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));

                    RoundRect(lpnmCD->hdc, lpnmCD->rc.left + 3,
                        lpnmCD->rc.top + 3,
                        lpnmCD->rc.right - 3,
                        lpnmCD->rc.bottom - 3, 5, 5);

                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (hBitmap != NULL)
            DeleteObject((HBITMAP)hBitmap);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Try to make some modifications to "if" conditions to meet your needs.

Comment: Custom draw message does not return BOOL

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't mater here, since it was just a sample. Like that I don't care about how to set every month 10th, just use flag instead. The most important thing is detecting click on and filling color in button.